# Firebug giving jQuery "$ is undefined" error even when jQuery is loaded before the script

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK so I have a WordPress site. It uses quite a few jQuery scripts and jQuery is loaded in the pages' headers. I have a small block of code that should simple add a class to image links. I have placed this at the bottom of the document, just before the `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a[href*=".png"], a[href*=".gif"], a[href*=".jpg"]').addClass('zoom');
});
</script>
```

The script does not work and Firebug is giving me a `$ is undefined` error. I have checked various similar other question and the answers do not seem to help.

The source page is here: http://sergedenimes.com/2013/01/bruno-bisang-30-years-of-polaroids/

I'm sure it is another plugin causing a conflict but I would appreciate any guidance on how to solve this.

Edit: Wow thanks for the very rapid response. Seems it was an earlier plugin rendering `$` undefined. Replacing with `jQuery` has solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.noConflict();` makes the `$` symbol go back to it's previous definition before jQuery was loaded.  If there were no other libraries using that symbol, then it goes back to `undefined`.  That is its purpose.

If you're going to use that and not define any other symbol as a shortcut for `jQuery`, then you must use `jQuery` as the symbol for jQuery functions instead of `$`.

Do this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('a[href*=".png"], a[href*=".gif"], a[href*=".jpg"]').addClass('zoom');
});
</script>
```

or, if you're only trying to use `$` inside the `.ready()` handler, then you can assign it using a feature of `.ready()` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('a[href*=".png"], a[href*=".gif"], a[href*=".jpg"]').addClass('zoom');
});
</script>
```

or if you have code that isn't just in the `.ready()` handler that wants to use `$`, you can redefine `$` in a closure which lets other libraries use `$` in their own code, but you can use it for jQuery in your jQuery code inside the closure:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[href*=".png"], a[href*=".gif"], a[href*=".jpg"]').addClass('zoom');
    });
    $.each(whatever...)
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

or, you can define a new shortcut symbol for jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $$ = $.noConflict();
$$(document).ready(function () {
    $$('a[href*=".png"], a[href*=".gif"], a[href*=".jpg"]').addClass('zoom');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Strictly speaking it does not make `$` `undefined`, it assigns whatever value it had before jQuery was included. And aliasing is easier if you just name the first argument passed to the ready handler: `jQuery(function($) {...});`

Comment: @FelixKling - your comments have been incorporated into my answer.  Thx.

Answer (score 6):

You already did `jQuery.noConflict();` earlier in your code thereby making `$` undefined.

Look at line 79 of your source code.

[image]

Comment: So tell the OP how to fix it!

Comment: @epascarello I did! Use `jQuery` because `$` is undefined!

Comment: You did not spell it out for the OP. ;) When I put on my "I do not know what you are talking about hat" saying $ is undefined tells me nothing on how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('a[href*=".png"], a[href*=".gif"], a[href*=".jpg"]').addClass('zoom');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yes its an alias http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers

Comment: Yes it seems WordPress loads in noconflict mode causing $ to be undefined unless otherwise otherwise told to be.